# How add different Icons per row inside a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying this cool library that uses Ken Burn effect [here (his github page)](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar) 
I got it to work but I cant add different Icons on different rows.  I tried to use Mkyongs CustomAdaptor example but what he used is a layout with TextView and ImageView.  What I am using is ListView.  I am already able to change the text font and size of the ListView but lost trying to add icons.  How do you do this?

Below is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blur4"
    tools:context="com.gio.hia.hiarewired.NoBoringActionBarActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height">

        <com.gio.hia.hiarewired.KenBurnsView
            android:id="@+id/header_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/picture0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_logo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/header_logo_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_logo_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_header_logo" />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is my Activity Class

```
private void setupListView() {
    ArrayList<String> FAKES = new ArrayList<String>();
    //for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        FAKES.add("Row 1");
    FAKES.add("Row 2");
    FAKES.add("Row 3");
    FAKES.add("Row 4");
    //}
    mPlaceHolderView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_header_placeholder, mListView, false);
    mListView.addHeaderView(mPlaceHolderView);
    //mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FAKES));
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_text_config, FAKES));
    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() { ...
```

I used a custom R.layout.list_text_config to change the font

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>
```

In his example he used a layout inflater How do I use my Custom Adapter with a layout inflator or am I looking at the problem on the wrong direction?
I usually just do this

```
CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but how do I do that when he used a layout inflater like below

```
mPlaceHolderView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_header_placeholder, mListView, false);
    mListView.addHeaderView(mPlaceHolderView);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FAKES));
```

Comment: You have to create custom adapter to do this.

Comment: From tutorials I usually do it like this 
 CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

but I dont know how to use that with the example code for the KenBurns library because he used
' mPlaceHolderView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_header_placeholder, mListView, false);
        mListView.addHeaderView(mPlaceHolderView);
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FAKES)); '

Comment: Have you done it yet ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Arslan yes I have done it using the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Arslan said this can be done with a custom adapter.  You are actually doing it correct

```
CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

That actually creates the list with the icons.  What you need to add to that is the header image to the mPlaceHolderView but instead of using **mListView** use the **list** that you created with your "custom adapter".  I placed the modified line of code from the original line of code so you can easily see the difference.

```
    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mPlaceHolderView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_header_placeholder, list, false);        
    //mPlaceHolderView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_header_placeholder, mListView, false);      
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now and since your no longer using the **mListView** you should probably lookout for instances of **mListView** and replace it with your **list**

Comment: Thank you I feel so dumb I was so confused to the point that I was passing the adapter to the mListView.